# Cant find symbol 'R' , android

Tags: android, web-services, spinner

Im working with android! i was doing fine until when i run my app and from no where, i had this error.

```
Cant find symbol 'R'
```

for example here:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
```

I get this output to:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Hoteles:processDebugResources'.
Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':Hoteles:processDebugResources'
```

I've already tried to Rebuild proyect and Sync proyect with gradle files.
How could i solve this? My app was almost finished.

Comment: You could try deleting your R file, which will force it to generate a new one. This is a pretty common error, so there are lots of tips out there.

Comment: if the above doesn't work, make sure there are no errors in your xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working with Android Studio for you Android development. if so have a look on this [post](http://spacetech.dk/android-studio-0-1-6-cannot-find-symbol-location-class-r.html)

Answer (score 0):

You try thus ways. Such as

1. May be you are mistake any resource
2. Clean the project.
3. gen folder delete.
4. may be import android.R
5. if import android.R then delete android.R and replace package name.R for exampe, com.example.imageview.R

Answer (score 0):

Have you made a default package? If you've made a default package it won't see the generated files which should contain R.java

**The package you use should have the exact same package name as the package in the "gen" folder, there should never be a case where you need to import R.java**

Click the "gen" folder and click the package with your project name  (should be something like "com.example.whatever")  now click that to display its contents, is R.java in there? Because it should be, if it isn't in there then now you know that there is a problem with one of your XML files. The compiler will not generate R.java if there is a problem in one of the XML files, it could either be a layout file or the manifest.